# How to set up cache in next.js server side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, caching, next.js

I'm trying to use 'node-cache' in nextjs backend but seems not working.
Here my cache file

cache.ts

```
import NodeCache from 'node-cache';
const Cache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 60 * 60 * 6 }); // 6 hours
export default Cache;
```

When request hit API1, i will do some calculation and save the result in node-cache

API1

```
import Cache from '@/utils/cache';

async function fetchFromUrl(url: string): Promise<UrlContent | null> {
  try {
    const cachedContent = Cache.get<UrlContent>(url);
    if (cachedContent) {
      return cachedContent;
    }

    ....

    Cache.set(url, cleanedContent);
    console.log(url, Cache.keys(), Cache.get(url)); // i can get results here
    return cleanedContent;
  }
```

But when another request hit API2, i can't fetch data from the cache.

API2

```
import Cache from '@/utils/cache';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    // Handle any methods other than POST
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  } else {
    // Extract urls from the request body
    const { urls, question } = req.body as UrlRequestBody;
    if (!urls || !Array.isArray(urls) || urls.length === 0 || !question) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid request body' });
    }

    console.log(
      urls[0] as string,
      question,
      Cache.keys(), // no key returned
      Cache.get(urls[0] as string) // can't get the results
    );
```